# Do I need to close a ByteArrayInputStream?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, inputstream

Short question,

I saw in some old code where a `ByteArrayInputStream` was created like:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(somebytes)));
```

And then the `BufferedReader` is used to read out `somebytes` line by line.
All working fine, but I noticed that the `BufferedReader` is never closed.
This is all working in a long running websphere application, the `somebytes` are not terrible big (200k most), it is only invoked a few times a week and we're not experiencing any apparent memory leaks. So I expect that all the objects are successfully garbage collected.

I always (once) learned that input/output streams need to be closed, in a `finally` statement. Are `ByteStreams` the exception to this rule?

kind regards
Jeroen.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and hints! As a commenter below pointed out it was a matter of RTFM or "Have you googled it?" as the latter did almost immediately reveal the answer. However to my knowledge it was unasked at stackoverflow till now, and the bonus was the hints aside

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You don't have to close `ByteArrayInputStream`, the moment it is not referenced by any variable, garbage collector will release the stream and `somebytes` (of course assuming they aren't referenced somewhere else).

**However** it is always a good practice to close every stream, in fact, maybe the implementation creating the stream will change in the future and instead of raw bytes you'll be reading file? Also static code analyzing tools like PMD or <strike>FindBugs</strike> (see comments) will most likely complain.

If you are bored with closing the stream and being forced to handle impossible `IOException`, you might use [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.InputStream%29):

```
IOUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
```

Comment: I think there's probably a few more impossible `IOException`s in there, given that the code is not actually dealing with any I/O at all!

Comment: findbugs is smart enough not to report BAIS/BAOS not being closed.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tacklin: the beauty of having checked exceptions :-(

Comment: Actually, you could get an EOF exception if used in certain ways, couldn't you?

Comment: So if the Stream/File/Reader/WhateverIoObject goes out of scope it's automatically closed?

Comment: If `ByteArrayInputStream.close()` will never throw an `IOException`, there would be no good reason for `ByteArrayInputStream.close()` to declare that is `throws IOException`. Although `InputStream` declares it `throws`, an overriding method  may throw a sub set of the exceptions of the declared exceptions of the base class or interface. So either the Java implementers want to reserve the right for `ByteArrayInputStream.close()` to throw an exception, or they made a mistake.

Comment: We should add that there is try-with-resource since Java 7 which fixes most cases where closeQuietly-utils came in handy.

Comment: As @TomaszNurkiewicz mentioned it's always good to close the opened stream.

Comment: Closing a {@code ByteArrayInputStream} has no effect. The methods in
    this class can be called after the stream has been closed without
    generating an {@code IOException}.

From ByteArrayInputStream.java

Comment: IOUtils.closeQuietly(stream) is Deprecated

Answer (score 13):

It is always good practice to close your readers.  However not closing a ByteArrayInputStream does not have as heavy of a potential negative effect because you are not accessing a file, just a byte array in memory.

Comment: The documentation for ByteArrayInputStream will confirm that close() does nothing. But it's a good idea to stay in the practice of calling close on streams. You might later refactor to make a function accept other kinds of streams.

Answer (score 3):

As @TomaszNurkiewicz mentioned it's always good to close the opened stream. Another good way to let it do the try block itself. Use try with resource  like.......

```
try ( InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); Workbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream)) {
```

here Workbook and InputStream both implements Closeable Interface so once try block completes ( normally or abruptly), stream will be closed for sure.

Comment: I like try block but how do you return say a stream to caller?

Answer (score 1):

Resources need to be closed in a `finally` (or equivalent). But where you just have some bytes, no it doesn't matter. Although when writing, be careful to `flush` in the happy case.

Comment: `close()` by design must flush 1st.

Comment: @bestsss Doesn't matter how you call `flush`. No need to `close`. Might as well be explicit.